# Running a part of code after a hour

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Okay so i am storing some values in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), 
now as soon as i set these values, i wanna do something that after one hour, if the app is opened some part of code runs.

For example :

> imaging right now i set doIt as true. now after 1 hour from now when
>   the app is opened, i want to set doIt to false again.

where doIt is a SharedPreferences tag.

Comment: Use [alarm manager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#java).

Comment: JobScheduler on newer devices, AlarmManager on old ones.